# JQuery using .find to disable Radio input elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Through the HTML shown below I am trying to disable the two sRadio1 inputs or the two sRadio2 inputs if any of them are checked, so I tried using JQuery to do so as shown below but for some reason it is not working. Can someone please tell me what exactly I am doing wrong here and how to fix it? Thanks

```
        <ul class="soptionslist">
          <li>
            <h2>Options</h2>
            <ul class="soptions">

              <li>
                <fieldset>
                  <input type="radio" class="sRadio" name="sRadio1">
                </fieldset>
                <fieldset class="option2">
                  <input type="radio" class="sRadio" name="sRadio1">
                </fieldset>
                <p>Option A</p>
              </li>

              <li>
                <fieldset>
                  <input type="radio" class="sRadio" name="sRadio2">
                </fieldset>
                <fieldset class="option2">
                  <input type="radio" class="sRadio" name="sRadio2">
                </fieldset>
                <p>Option B</p>
              </li>                    
            </ul>
           </li>
          </ul>
```

JQuery code

```
  $(".soptions input").change(function() {
    if (this.checked) {
        $(this).parent('li').find('input').attr('disabled', true);
    } else {
        $(this).parent('li').find('input').attr('disabled', true);
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `closest()` instead of `parent()`

**Change to this:**

```
 $(".soptions input").change(function () {
     if (this.checked) {
         $(this).closest('li').find('input').prop('disabled', true);
     } else {
         $(this).closest('li').find('input').prop('disabled', true);
     }
 });
```

## **Compatibility:**

**For JQuery 1.6+:**

Use the [`.prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop) function:

```
$(this).closest('li').find('input').prop('disabled', true);
```

**For JQuery 1.5 and below:**

The `.prop()` function is not available, so you need to use [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr).

```
$(this).closest('li').find('input').attr('disabled', true);
```

## **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2zVfA/)**

Answer (score 0):

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/L4kw9/)

you need to use `.prop()` instead of `.attr()`

```
 $(".soptions input").change(function() {
    if (this.checked) {
        $(this).parent('li').find('input').prop('disabled', true);
    } else {
        $(this).parent('li').find('input').prop('disabled', true);
    }
  });
```

[`.prop()`reference](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)